# How to access java class member in instance with a string

Tags: java, class, arraylist, class-members

I have a small class with some data, called `MyData`:

```java
public class MyData {
    public String name = "";
    public String nameonly = "";
    public int id = 0;
    public double earn = 0;
    public double paid = 0;
    ....

    public MyData(String name, String nameonly, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nameonly = nameonly;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Then I have a class with arrays of this class for specific type of people called `AllMyData`:

```java
public class AllMyData {
    public ArrayList<MyData> cli = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<MyData> sub = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<MyData> emp = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<MyData> exp = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<MyData> oex = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<MyData> bin = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<MyData> ven = new ArrayList<>();
    ....
}
```

in main class I need to add new items to specific array (if `id` does not exists) where I have a string representative of `AllMyData` array

```java
public AllMyData elems = new AllMyData();

public void initArray(int id, String name, String tip) {
    //this is an example just for "cli" element and "cli" is in String tip
    if (!checkForId(elems.cli, id)) {
        MyData element = new MyData(name, name, id);
        elems.cli.add(element);
    }
}

private boolean checkForId(ArrayList<MyData> a, int id) {
    for (MyData e : a) {
        if (e.id == id) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then I need just a call, for example:

```java
initArray(5, "Test", "emp");
```

and would like to avoid switch statement and to repeat code for every single type. In this call, "emp" would be element `elems.emp`

Is there a way to access `elems` member with a string name instead of creating switch statement?

Comment: This really smells like a XY problem.

Comment: I suggest you write your code following naming conventions. As it stands, reading your code is quite confusing when you have variable names starting with upper case and class names starting with lower case.

Comment: @Gendarme I went ahead and capitalized the class names, because it was hard to look at.

Comment: I'm sorry, still newbie in Java...

Comment: To expain what the XY problem is: [asking how to implement a solution to a problem you had, rather than asking about how to properly solve _that_ problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In this case you're showing a _very strange way_ to do things: if you have different kinds of data, create a "master class" that encodes all the shared functionality, and extend that to specific classes that capture your different data types, one for each kind. Then you rely on java's strong typing to call the right methods based on type matching.

Comment: Probably my English is not so good, but my intention was to ask how to properly solve this problem :)

Comment: The problem is created by yourself writing this code to (presumably) solve another simpler problem. That is what the XY problem is. Your code design is very weird, and since this is neither a [mcve] nor a clear question (it's hard to understand what you're asking), it will be hard for anyone to properly answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a map of lists in `AllMyData` instead.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AllMyData data = new AllMyData();
        data.add("foo", new MyData("Hello World", "", 1));
        data.add("cli", Arrays.asList(new MyData("BASH", "", 2), new MyData("SHELL", "", 3)));
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

```
AllMyData [map={cli=[MyData [name=BASH, nameonly=, id=2, earn=0.0, paid=0.0], MyData [name=SHELL, nameonly=, id=3, earn=0.0, paid=0.0]], sub=[], oex=[], bin=[], foo=[MyData [name=Hello World, nameonly=, id=1, earn=0.0, paid=0.0]], emp=[], exp=[], ven=[]}]
```

```java
import java.util.*;

public class AllMyData {
    private Map<String, List<MyData>> map;

    public AllMyData() {
        map = new HashMap<String, List<MyData>>();

        map.put("cli", new ArrayList<>());
        map.put("sub", new ArrayList<>());
        map.put("emp", new ArrayList<>());
        map.put("exp", new ArrayList<>());
        map.put("oex", new ArrayList<>());
        map.put("bin", new ArrayList<>());
        map.put("ven", new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public void add(String key, List<MyData> data) {
        List<MyData> list = get(key);
        if (list == null) {
            map.put(key, data);
        } else {
            list.addAll(data);
            map.put(key, list);
        }
    }

    public void add(String key, MyData data) {
        List<MyData> list = get(key);
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        list.add(data);
        map.put(key, list);
    }

    public List<MyData> get(String key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("AllMyData [map=%s]", map);
    }
}
```

```java
public class MyData {
    public String name = "";
    public String nameonly = "";
    public int id = 0;
    public double earn = 0;
    public double paid = 0;

    public MyData(String name, String nameonly, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nameonly = nameonly;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("MyData [name=%s, nameonly=%s, id=%s, earn=%s, paid=%s]", name, nameonly, id, earn, paid);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.... it is totally different approach then mine. I am still a newbie in Java, just trying to "convert" my code I already have in AS3 to Java code.....

Answer (score 0):

Consider the use of a Map from String to ArrayList.

It would look like this:

`Map> allMyData = new HashMap<>();`